# Php log in allows entry with no user/pass

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, salt

Hey guys ive put together a basic user log in for a secure admin area and it seems to work great, if you enter a correct user/pass you get access, if you enter the wrong user pass, you get no access. However if you enter nothing in both fields you get access.

This is how it works.

Creating a user, a basic form POSTS to this php file.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(credentials are all good) or die(mysqli_error($con)) ; 

$escapedUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
$escapedPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

$some_str = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
$base_64str = base64_encode($some_str);
$modified_base64 = str_replace('+', '.', $base_64str);
$gensalt = substr($modified_base64, 0, 22);

$format_str = "$2y$10$"; // 2y for Blowfish and 10 times.
$salt = $format_str . $gensalt . "$";
$hashed_pass = crypt($escapedPass, $salt);

$query = "INSERT INTO `userpass` (`username`, `password`, `salt`) VALUES ('$escapedUser', '$hashed_pass', '$salt'); ";

if(isset($escapedUser) && isset($hashed_pass))
{
    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    header("Location: ausers.php");
    exit();
} 
Echo "Something went wrong!";
?>
```

The database appears to be storing these fine

We then log in with this code

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(again credentials are fine) or die(mysqli_error($con)) ; 

$escapedUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['user']);
$escapedPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass']);

$saltQuery = "select salt from userpass where username = '$escapedUser';";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $saltQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$salt = $row['salt'];
$hashed_pass = crypt($escapedPass, $salt);
if(isset($escapedUser) && isset($hashed_pass))
{
    $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM userpass WHERE username='$escapedUser' AND password='$hashed_pass'";
    $userpass = mysqli_query($con, $userQuery);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($userpass);
    if($count == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $escapedUser;
        header("location: aindex.php");
        exit();
    }
    header("Location: alogin.htm");
    exit();
}
Echo "Something went wrong!";
?>
```

So as i said, this seems to work fine for when any user pass combination is given whether access granted or denied however using no user and pass and pressing log in allows entry. Any ideas? THeres no blank rows in the database table.

Side question, is this salt/hash method correct, its my first attempt.

Comment: Why don't you just use one `"SELECT * FROM userpass WHERE username='$escapedUser'"`? Btw, look into prepared statements.

Comment: That said, perhaps you have a user with empty username and password in your database.

Answer (score 0):

For your login code, your condition relies on an `isset()` test. You perform this test on `$escapedUser` and `$hashed_pass`. Both of these variables were actually assigned values earlier in the code! Once you assign a value to the variable, it will pass the `isset()` test, even if the value is an empty string. You might want to use an `empty()` check, perhaps on the original $_POST variables.

Moving on to the inner condition, which tests if the mysql query returns exactly 1 row of results. If there were truly no rows with empty values, then this condition would never pass because the query would return 0 rows. But it is passing. Two things to consider:

- Notice that your registering code uses the same `isset()` test. Therefore it is very possible that someone used your registration form, submitted empty fields, and successfully registered a row with empty user and password fields. Have you explicitly queried your database for empty fields and actually come up with 0 results?
- Your query uses `SELECT *`. Perhaps this is causing the query to return some sort of aggregate value (like a COUNT() or something that always has a result no matter what). Perhaps try explicitly defining the columns to return?

I cannot comment on your salt/hash method as I have no experience in that part. Hope you find this helpful!

Comment: Sorry to make this clear, are you suggesting using something like if (!empty($escapedUser))

Comment: That is one possibility, but probably not the most secure. I would actually suggest testing `$_POST['user'])` and other post variables directly. How about your original question? Did that get resolved?

Comment: Hi toby, thanks for your help, wasnt able to do this something came up, ive implemented it now, first i tried testing `if (!empty($_POST['user']) && if (!empty($_POST['pass'])) {` however this made the script fail all together. Instead i've just defined `$_POST['user']` as `$user` and the same for password and then ran those variables through the if before escaping them and its working great now. Cant access without user/pass and the it only allows entry on correct combination! Thanks! I can't upvote your answer because you need a reputation above 15 and i have no idea how to get that?

Comment: I think the most robust way to check would be `if (isset($_POST["user"]) && !empty($_POST["user"]))`. I think you get an error because you can't POST variable that was never sent.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you need more than one level of checks in any form, whether it be registration, comments, login, etc. The way I prefer to go about it is a tiered approach. It may work better for you, but it's just an example.

By doing it this way, you ensure that your input will never be empty. Another issue I see with your login script is that you never compare the input with the database so how can you know if they entered the correct information? The only thing allowing them to login is that the query returned a record. This is also why they can login with a blank form.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(again credentials are fine) or die(mysqli_error($con)) ;

/* Ensures that form was submitted before any processing is done */
if (isset($_POST)) {

$User = $_POST['user']);
$Pass = $_POST['pass']);

if (!empty($User)) {

if (!empty($Pass)) {

$escapedUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $User);
$escapedPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $Pass);

/* you need to verify the password here, before adding the salt */
$saltQuery = "select salt from userpass where username = '$escapedUser'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $saltQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$salt = $row['salt'];
$hashed_pass = crypt($escapedPass, $salt);

    $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM userpass WHERE username='$escapedUser' AND password='$hashed_pass'";
/* you need to verify the username somewhere here */
    $userpass = mysqli_query($con, $userQuery);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($userpass);
    if($count == 1)
    {

        $_SESSION['username'] = $escapedUser;
        header("location: aindex.php");
        exit();
    } else {
    header("Location: alogin.htm");
    exit();
    }


} else {
    echo "Please enter a password.";
}

} else {
    echo "Please enter a username.";
}

} else {
    echo "You have not entered any information.";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm very confused what you mean by verify the password before adding the salt. There's no plain text password stored just the salt and the hashed password which uses the salt.

Comment: What I mean, is that when the user types in the password, it doesn't include the salt so you won't be able to compare it. I am not familiar with crypt so I can't advise on how to do it.